# Is there a chrome extension which gives you a hotkey for clicking on the first result of a google search?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

Minor question: does there exist a chrome extension which gives you a hotkey for clicking on the first result of a google search? (I'm running Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 3):

You dont need an Extension..
You can modify the default google search engine to search as "I'm Feeling Lucky"..
That'll take you to the first result.

Do this :

```
Go to Options > Basic > Default Search > Manage..
```

Add a new search engine with the specification

```
URL: http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI=Im+Feeling+Lucky
```

Now search and check if it works as you want it.. :)

Comment: Cool! Its not what I wanted though: I want to be able to search first, and then if the first hit is correct, select it from the keyboard (and if not then make the long journey to the mouse).

Comment: Dude, For that, Go here.. http://superuser.com/questions/107524/keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-com/107560#107560

Comment: Once you have enabled Google Instant keyboard shortcuts http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=191139 , use the Down key. If Down does not work, try hitting Tab first, followed by Down